# When ever I want to load XML file exception occur: System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: xml, xamarin.android

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='yes'?>
<Collection>
    <Book Id='1' ISBN='1-100000ABC-200'>
        <Title>Principle of Relativity</Title>
        <!-- Famous physicist -->      
        <Author>Albert Einstein</Author>
        <Genre>Physics</Genre>
    </Book>
    <Book Id='2' ISBN='1-100000ABC-300'>
        <!-- Also came as a TV serial -->
        <Title>Cosmos</Title>
        <Author>Carl Sagan</Author>
        <Genre>Cosmology</Genre>
    </Book>
    <!-- Add additional books here -->
</Collection>
```

When application start after 3 sec this exception occur:

> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Why this exception is occurring while this XML code is correct and loading in console application and there is no exception occurring in console application.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

namespace App16
{
    [Activity(Label = "App16", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("Q317664.xml");
            // var doc = XDocument.Load("Q317664.xml");

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided XML has an error. Collection node is not ended properly.

Can you try with this XML? And check if problem is solved?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='yes'?>
<Collection>
    <Book Id='1' ISBN='1-100000ABC-200'>
    <Title>Principle of Relativity</Title>
    <!-- Famous physicist -->      
    <Author>Albert Einstein</Author>
        <Genre>Physics</Genre>
    </Book>
    <Book Id='2' ISBN='1-100000ABC-300'>
        <!-- Also came as a TV serial -->
        <Title>Cosmos</Title>
        <Author>Carl Sagan</Author>
        <Genre>Cosmology</Genre>
    </Book>
</Collection>
```

Comment: i checked it but same exception Collection tag is properly closed in my xml file sorry here is missing Colllection closing tag @Jack Morton